# How do I add an options page at the bottom of the list?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, admin-menu

I'm working on my first plugin, and I'm using something like this to add a submenu under Settings:

```
add_options_page(
    'Page Title',
    'Menu Title',
    'edit_theme_options',
    'my-plugin-menu-slug',
    array($this, 'options_page')
);
```

The trouble is that this adds the entry on the top of the submenu, as pictured below.

[image: wp-admin menu]

How can I get it to add the entry at the end of the list instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `add_options_page` make sure to call it on the `admin_menu` action/event, so it's called at the correct time

```
add_action('admin_menu', function () {
    add_options_page( .... );
} );
```

You may be able to gain further control by specifying the priority of the action in the `add_action` call

Comment: Thanks! I had been calling it from `init` instead of `admin_menu`. This did the trick!